# Can I use "Self." to Simplify This Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, class

This is my code:

```
function o1()
{
    $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");
    document.getElementById('ho1').classList.add('headerbtnsel');
}
function o2()
{
    $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");
    document.getElementById('ho2').classList.add('headerbtnsel');
}
function o3()
{
    $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");
    document.getElementById('ho3').classList.add('headerbtnsel');
}
```

I want to make it so that all these functions can just be one. I want to make it so that instead of using the getElement, you could use self or something like that. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: `function myO(idx) {  $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");
    $('.ho'+idx).addClass('headerbtnsel'); }`

Comment: thanks! I can't believe I didn't think about that!

Comment: Didn't seem to work but I changed slightly so now this works:    function     o(idx)
 {
  $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");
  $(idx).addClass('headerbtnsel');
 }

Comment: I expected `myO(1)`, not `myO(".ho1")` - whatever works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify my comment

```
function myO(idx) { 
  $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");        
  $('.ho'+idx).addClass('headerbtnsel');   
}
```

using `myO(1)` for ho1

OR

```
function myO(headerClass) { 
  $(".headerbtn").removeClass("headerbtnsel");        
  $("."headerClass).addClass('headerbtnsel');   
}
```

using `myO('ho1')` for ho1